# Unable to find package Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools with version (>= 2.1.0) While Upgrading to .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to upgrade to my project from 2.0 to .Net Core 2.1.

I am using the following link as guide though it was for preview:

- [Upgrading to .NET 2.1](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/upgrading-aspnet-core-2-application-aspnet-core-2-1-preview-1)

I am currently aware that the Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools package is only at version 2.0.2 based on the nuget link: [nuget package link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools/)

For more details, please see the issue I logged on the .Net Core GitHub page [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1639)

Note:

1. .Net Core 2.1 is installed:
   [image: .Net core version]
2. All DotNetCLIReferences were removed

Questions:

1. Why is there no 2.1.0 version of the Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools nuget package after an official release of .Net Core 2.1.0?
2. Is it possible to resolve this error or do I have to roleback my project to .Net Core 2.0?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove most of your DotNetCliToolReference's in your csproj file in 2.1. Many of the tools such as secretmanager are now global tools which you'll have if you're running the 2.1 SDK. They no longer need to be referenced and brought into your project.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I did remove the DotNetCliToolReferences in my csproj file

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for `dotnet install tool --global dotnet-user-secrets`

Comment: I thought it was there as part of the SDK. If you run, dotnet user-secrets do you get any output?

Comment: @stevejgordon Thats what I thought too. yes i get output - "No secrets configured for this application."

Comment: @stevejgordon shouldnt the Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools nuget package have a version 2.1.0 based on the error message? Or thats the point of this tool being a part of the SDK?The latest version is '2.0.2'.

Comment: The global tool comes from https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-user-secrets/. I think that existing NuGet package is essentially depreciated. What is the error you are seeing and when does it occur?

Comment: You may need to re-register your secrets if it's empty.

Comment: @stevejgordon But do I need secrets? I dont have any configured for this application. Meaning I didnt set any for the .net core 2.0 app and it was working fine

Comment: @stevejgordon I figured it out. Your comments were helpful. You can vote up the answer

Comment: @Hue what is the solution.  I am stuck here too.

Comment: Just follow the steps in the migration guide. @stevejgordon posted a link to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out

Apparently I had referenced the Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools package twice, as a DotNetCliReference and as a regular package reference. When I finally removed both references and the secret key information the error was resolved.

I ended up with this because the error initially was complaining that I needed to add the Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools  version greater or equal to 2.1.0, which clearly does not exist

See screenshots below:

Part 1:

[image: solution screenshot 1]

Part 2:

[image: solution screenshot 2]

Thanks to everyone in the comments, their comments ultimately assisted me in thinking about the error and double checking.